# Why is a boolean 4 bytes in .NET?

Tags: .net

Why does a System.Boolean take 4 bytes?  It just stores one state, either *true* or *false*, which could be stored in less space than 4 bytes.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A `bool` is actually only 1 byte, but alignment may cause 4 bytes to be used on a 32-bit platform, or even 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform.  For example, the `Nullable<bool>` (aka `bool?`) type uses a full 32 or 64 bits—depending on platform—even though it's comprised of just two `bool`s.  **EDIT**: As pointed out by Jon Skeet, padding for alignment isn't *always* present.  As an example, an array of `Nullable<bool>`s takes only 2 bytes per object instead of 4 or 8.

But even 8 bits to represent a `bool` can be considered wasteful if you have many of them to store.  For this reason, if you create a type that has many `bool`s as members, (or uses many `Nullable<>` types), **and** users of your class might create many instances of it, you might consider using a `BitVector32` instead.  The framework itself uses this technique to reduce the memory footprint of many of the Windows Forms controls, for instance.

Comment: Even Nullable<bool> will only use up two bytes in some cases - for instance if you've got an array of them.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I would have expected it to align array indices for performance's sake, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: This is an artifact of the C standard library and compiler. Most compilers on 32-bits and 64-bits platforms where memory is not really an issue optimize for performance, not code size. Bools are not packed by the compiler into bitfields, unless done explicitly in a struct. This is to keep adequate performance when passing pointers, otherwise you not only have to dereference but also mask on every access.

Answer (score 14):

Because it's fast.

A 32-bit processor typically works with 32-bit values. Working with smaller values involves longer instructions, or extra logic.

Answer (score 5):

The first result on a Google search for [System.Boolean size](http://www.google.com/search?q=system.boolean+size) told me that it's to do with memory alignment. It's faster to push around a four-byte Int32 than it is to work with individual bytes/bits.

Comment: Today's first Google answer is this question. Since questions are archived, please add also the specific link in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's only for performance, 32 bit values are much more efficient to manipulate.

Answer (score 2):

Where'd you get that? System.Boolean takes only **1** byte.

Just try:

```
Console.WriteLine( sizeof( System.Boolean ).ToString() );
```

Comment: Check the size after the type has been marshaled: Console.Write(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(new System.Boolean()));

Comment: Which is what you shouldn't do. Most of the unmanaged API's use *int* for BOOL values, Marhsal.SizeOf() tells you size of an *unmanaged* type.

Comment: Marshalling a bool is slighly more complicated than that.  I did a blog post on this subject which covers the various sizes: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/14/pinvoke-and-bool-or-should-i-say-bool.aspx

Comment: I used the GC.GetTotalMemory to check it... my post was too long to fit here in the replies but I added it as a response to this question for anyone who is interested.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to create a couple arrays and test them.  float?[100000] uses twice as much memory as float[100000].  This is because the bool that accompanies the float in the float? case gets aligned to 32 bits (at least on my machine ;-) )

```
long startMem = 0, stopMem = 0;
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
private void StartMemoryUsage()
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.Collect();
    startMem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
}
private void StopMemoryUsage()
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.Collect();
    stopMem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

    Console.WriteLine("---> {0} sec.  Using {1} KB.", (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds, ((stopMem - startMem) / 1000).ToString());
}
```