# How to represent a very large bit array efficiently?

Tags: c#, .net, bit, memory-optimization

Since [a boolean actually takes 1 byte of space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294905/why-in-net-system-boolean-takes-4-byte), a `bool[]` isn't the most space-efficient way to represent a bit array. Sometimes integers and longs are used as a more efficient bit array, but a long can only hold 64 bits. Is there a more space-efficient way to store arrays of tens of millions bits in limited memory?

All I need to do with this array is to set/clear individual bits and to check whether some bits is 1 or 0, i.e. the only functions I need:

```
void Set(int index, bool value);
bool Get(int index);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you need is [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class

Comment: Biggest issue with this class is that it doesn't implement the appropriate generic collection interfaces. Probably not a problem for the OP if he only needs those two operations though.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: And what kind of generic type will you expose? Your point is moot.

Comment: @leppie Implementing `IList<bool>` would have been appropriate IMO. I'm a bit surprised they didn't add that with .net 2.0, just like they added it to normal arrays.

Comment: @CodesInChaos from the docs it seems that this does not support operations that changes the length of the array. So probably implementing `IList<bool>` will make it more complicated.

Comment: @CodesInChaos And you can still use `bitArray.OfType<bool>().ToList()`

Comment: @LouisRhys Just throw `NotSupportedException` just like they already do for arrays or their `ICollection` implementation on `BitArray`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't think it's a good idea. If people pass around BitArray as IList, they will get NotSupportedException without expecting it.

Comment: @LouisRhys The same issue applies to `bool[]`. You can't change the size of normal arrays either. IMO `BitArray` should mirror the semantics of `bool[]` as closely as possible, apart from the more efficient storage. | The design of .net's interfaces is dumb, but that's a different issue.