# Does sizeof() in c# return only a size of type itself or it counts the reference size as well

Tags: c#, memory

If I do

```
class x
{
    int a; // here we have 2 integers, each reference has 4 bytes itself
    int b;
    public int GetSize()
    {
        // this function is supposed to return size of the class in operating memory in bytes
        return sizeof(int) * 2;
        // OR should it be this?
        return sizeof(int) * 2 + IntPtr.Size * 2;
    }
}
```

If I call sizeof on some type, such as int or double, does it return how much of ram the value uses? Or it also count the size of reference itself. I know that every reference in c# eats at least 4 bytes (hence the bool and such, usually memory inexpensive types, are quite memory expensive in c#).

If I wanted to know how much operating memory precisely `int x = 5;` eats should I count only `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(int) + IntPtr.Size`?

NOTE: I know that `Marshal.SizeOf` allows you to call some special function which returns a precise size of unmanaged object / type, but that seems too slow to me. I need a way to get a size of object which is eating as less cpu as possible so I would prefer to just use native sizeof()

Comment: "Or it also count the size of reference itself." What reference?

Comment: In your above example int is a value type i dont think it has a pointer at all

Comment: @hvd the pointer itself. As I understand it, in c# is everything object. So when I create new integer as int x = 23; it creates a new object of type Int32 and reference (pointer) to that object

Comment: @Petr Your understanding is wrong. `int` does derive from `object`, but that doesn't make it a reference type.

Comment: ok, but if my class contained some "reference type" for example instance of another class, how would I programatically measure its size? Also if int is not a reference type, does it mean that having instance of integer in my code, doesn't eat even 1 bit more operating memory than what sizeof(int) tell me?

Comment: having say that, in my case return sizeof(int) * 2; would return the precise size of the class in operating memory?

Comment: Consider a) We may do better if we know what problem you're trying to solve, rather than what looks like you're trying to see if `sizeof` fits your needs, and b) When you are dealing with an object, there can be any number of references to it. There isn't just (necessarily) one reference to the object.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the problem is obviously, that I need to retrieve a size of an object in operating memory (as effectively as possible, less cpu expensive is better than more accurate in my case)

Comment: @Petr - really? Your entire program determines the size, and then does nothing with that information and exits? What I'm getting at is - how were you planning to *use* this size information?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I want to set up a memory limit for array. So that it can never exceed defined size (in bytes - that array is array of some classes). And my "entire program" is an example I wrote for stack overflow, the original version, of course, contains more code...

Comment: @Petr - and you see, where now getting *closer* to your *actual* problem. But if you're trying to *find* the size of the object before you can define a "memory limit", that presumably means you're performing some calculation to which the size is just one input variable. So are you, in fact, trying to create an array/collection that can only contain a *fixed* number of instances?

Comment: not really a fixed number of instances, because the size of each instance can differ (the class contains some strings as well and they may have variable size). only thing that needs to be fixed is maximal operating memory used per array

Answer (score 5):

Everything in your question is wrong.

> Or it also count the size of reference itself.

There is no reference here.

> bool and such, usually memory inexpensive types, are quite memory expensive in c#

No, they are not. Such types are *value types*, they do not use a reference and consequently incur no overhead. The size of such types is just that type itself.

But the same is true for reference types: a structure containing two references has as its size the size of two references. It does *not* additionally have the size of the memory behind those references.

> NOTE: I know that Marshal.SizeOf allows you to call some special function which returns a precise size of unmanaged object / type, but that seems too slow to me.

It’s not slow.

> I need a way to get a size of object which is eating as less cpu as possible

What makes you think that `Marshal.SizeOf` is any slower than `sizeof`?

> so I would prefer to just use native sizeof()

There’s no such thing as “native” in C#. Even if there were, `sizeof` is not more native than `Marshal.SizeOf`.

Anyway, using `sizeof` on all the class’ members and adding their sizes is wrong because it ignores [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding) (this won’t be an issue in your particular example but it is in general).

In addition to all of the above, your approach is probably wrong anyway. Why do you need to know the size of the type? Chances are you can’t do anything meaningful with it. In particular, `Marshal.SizeOf` only works meaningfully with unmanaged types because its sole purpose is to determine how much memory has to be allocated via `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.

Comment: maybe everything was wrong in my question, but boolean indeed takes 4 bytes in c#, which is more than, for example in c

Comment: @Petr `sizeof(bool)` returns 1

Comment: my question wasn't worded well, that is true, but this doesn't answer it (I will try to improve) I don't want to know how much memory my object eats as a structure containing 2 references. I need to know how much /real/ memory the object eats - and all its child objects / types / references recursively. So that I just know how much operating memory is taken by the object, and eventually how much would be freed if I remove the object from it.

Comment: @jszigeti http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294905/why-in-net-system-boolean-takes-4-byte

Comment: @Petr You have misunderstood the question you link to. A `bool` takes 1 byte.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes i don't want to use profiler. I need to retrieve this information programatically so that I can set up a "virtual memory limit" - say you want to create an array of some object, and you never want this array to allocate more than 20mb of operating memory.

Comment: @KonradRudolph from what I have found so far, bool is 1 byte only in array but 4 bytes as a local variable

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes are you sure that something what is trivial in other languages is so complicated in c# as having to write own profiler just to get a size of object?

Comment: I don't know any language where this is trivial.

Comment: @Petr probably because the runtime aligns the stack to four bytes.

Comment: Can't the argument be made that the .NET framework exists so that you don't have to worry about memory allocations like this? Why not use C, if it is so critical to have exact memory details?

Comment: @Petr - then maybe what you're after is a [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx).

Comment: @jszigeti do you mean it's not possible in c# but it is in c? Writing this in c would be quite complicated given the features of c standard libraries compared to what you can find in .net / c#... it would be certainly more complicated than writing this in c# (just now the original application which was written in c has source code almost 200 times longer than its c# equivalent that can do exactly the same, just doesn't handle memory limits well)

Comment: @Petr I don't personally know how to do it in either C or C#, but I do know that the reason you're having difficulties achieving it in C# is because .NET is abstracting the memory allocation from you (because as you say, it is very complicated).