# Json.NET: How to perform implicit conversion of an object before serializing?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a class that has lots of 'optional bools'-- boolean values that may be true, false, or null. The most common way to represent this in .NET is to use `bool?`, however that takes up at least 2 bytes in memory (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/294942/4077294)), so I wrote my own `OptionalBool` struct that only takes up 1 byte and is implicitly convertible to `bool?`.

My question is, I have a class like this:

```
public class PartnerLoginOptions
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DeviceModel { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public OptionalBool IncludeUrls { get; set; }
    public OptionalBool ReturnDeviceType { get; set; }
    public OptionalBool ReturnUpdatePromptVersions { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get Json.NET to perform the implcit conversion from `OptionalBool` to `bool?` while serializing? For example if `IncludeUrls` was `default(OptionalBool)` (which is 'null'), `ReturnDeviceType` was true and `ReturnUpdatePromptVersions` was false, then the outputted JSON would look something like

```
{
    "includeUrls": null,
    "returnDeviceType": true,
    "returnUpdatePromptVersions": false
}
```

How can I do this given a `PartnerLoginOptions` object? The code I have so far is

```
var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```

**edit:** In case it's useful, [here](https://github.com/jamesqo/Pandorum/blob/master/src/Pandorum.Core.Optional/Core/OptionalBool.cs) is the source code for `OptionalBool`.

Comment: Did you have a look at creating a custom json converter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really want to do this you can define custom converter for `OptionalBool`:

```
public class OptionalBoolConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(OptionalBool) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var converted = (bool?) (OptionalBool) value;

        writer.WriteValue(converted);
    }
}
```

And then use it this way:

```
var test = new PartnerLoginOptions
        {
            ReturnDeviceType = true,
            ReturnUpdatePromptVersions = false
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Converters = new JsonConverter[] {new OptionalBoolConverter()}
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Answering your question, you can do the following:

```
public class PartnerLoginOptions
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DeviceModel { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public OptionalBool IncludeUrls { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IncludeUrls")]
    public bool? IncludeUrlsConverted 
    { 
        get { return (bool?)IncludeUrls; } // your conversion here
        set { IncludeUrls = (OptionalBool)value; } // your backwards conversion here
    }
}
```

or you can write your own `JsonConverter`.

However, for me it looks like your `OptionalBool` is an overengineering. 
2 bytes is absolutely not much, I cannot imagine the case when it is really required, whilst it creates so much incompatibility problems, produces converters and different hacks, and decreases readability.
Consider changing to `bool?`.